# usr/bin/env: bad interpreter Permission Denied --> how to change the fstab

Tags: python, permissions, cygwin

I'm using cygwin on windows 7 to run a bash script that activates a python script, and I am getting the following error:

`myscript.script: /cydrive/c/users/mydrive/folder/myscript.py: usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission Denied.`

I'm a total newbie to programming, so I've looked around a bit, and I think this means Python is mounted on a different directory that I don't have access to. However, based on what I found, I have tried to following things:

- Change something (from user to exec) in the fstab: however, my fstab file is all commented out and only mentions what the defaults are. I don't know how I can change the defaults. The fstab.d folder is empty.
- change the #! usr/bin/env python line in the script to the actual location of Python: did not work, same error
- add a PYTHONPATH to the environment variables of windows: same error.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with a suggestion!

Comment: You didn't post the first line of `myscript.py` (the #! line), and since this is the line causing the error, it's hard to diagnose anything....

Answer (score 14):

In my case the problem was in the missing executable flag on the file.

The solution for me was in the following code

```
chmod +x ./executed_file
```

Answer (score 9):

You script should start with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env whateverelse ...
   ^ this first one is important
```

Comment: You mean `#!/usr/bin/env python`, that space is important too.

Comment: `Blanks after ! are OK.` -- Dennis Ritchie . I had other experience, but that must have been an error in the implementation... You're right.  Upvoted; I learned something :-)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't really matter. I just find it prettier with a space :)

Comment: Hm, so I tried changing that and it didn't work. I get the same error (although now it's /usr/bin/env  etc...)

Comment: Well, does `/usr/bin/env` exist? Is it executable? Can you run it from the command line?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` should work. The `env` hack has some drawbacks; see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a late answer, but may be useful for others. I got the same kinda error, when I was trying to run a shell script which used python. Please check \usr\bin for existence of python. If not found, install that to solve the issue. I come to such a conclusion, as the error shows "bad interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to '**run cygwin as administrator'** Thanks. 
EDIT:- try chmod for permissions read for more [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/)

Answer (score 0):

You should write your command as 'python ./example.py ',then fix it in your script.

Answer (score 0):

This was in Git Bash for me. I changed the first line (shebang line) of the .py file being run, leaving the original, adding the one above it, and that worked:

```
#!python
#!C:\Users\Emiri\Anaconda\envs\_build\python.exe
```

*("Emiri" doesn't exist on my system, was hardcoded in a zipline install)*

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used cmder and started bash as Admin instead of WSL[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can disable `SELinux` by using:

```
setEnforce 0
```

More [info](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) about how to use `SELinux`