# cygwin "Permission denied"

Tags: c, cygwin, file-permissions

Trying to launch a file

```
./cu/cu-check-regressions --help
```

Get this:

```
-bash: ./cu/cu-check-regressions: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Already changed permission in properties>security my account has full control over the folder. Tried running cygwin as Administrator did not work as well. Googled the issue for the past two hours.

Comment: Did you try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716357/usr-bin-env-bad-interpreter-permission-denied-how-to-change-the-fstab)?

Comment: Yes I did, fruitless

Comment: @DanielKleinstein: That's unlikely to help if `/usr/bin/python` itself is not executable, which seems to be the problem here.

Comment: I don't even know to what is it referring, The cygwin directory does not have the path specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that `/usr/bin/python`, the Python interpreter, is not executable.

Run

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
```

or

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python.exe
```

to confirm this.

Running

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/python
```

is likely to fix the immediate problem. But the question remains: Why is `/usr/bin/python` not executable? Execution permission is set when it's installed. Have you been messing around with the `/usr/bin` directory? Its contents are managed by Cygwin; there should rarely be any need to touch it.

Based on your comment, it seems likely that Python just isn't installed (though that's not the error message I'd expect in that case). As I recall, Cygwin doesn't install Python by default. Re-run the installation command (`setup-x86.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe`, depending on which one you're using) and install (or reinstall) the `python` package; I think it's under "Interpreters".

Comment: ls: cannot access /usr/bin/python.exe: No such file or directory. I have not been messing around with anything. Last week I reinstalled my OS and while installing cygwin i did not change anything. Why would i mess around with something unfamiliar to me?

Comment: That's not the error message I'd expect if Python isn't installed. But as I recall Cygwin doesn't install Python by default. Run the Cygwin setup command (`setup-x86.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe`, depending on which one you're using) and install (or reinstall) Python. (I'm not saying *you'd* mess around with something unfamiliar, but plenty of people do.)

Comment: I do not have python on my laptop and I did not install anything related to python. EDIT: while reinstalling found some python related packages

Comment: @FancyPants: Well, if you don't have Python on your laptop, and `./cu/cu-check-regressions` is a Python script, that would certainly explain why you can't run it.

Comment: Might be.  I reinstalled it fully and it worked. Thank you for your help